# YUI - Set padding style to drag node

Tags: css, dom, yui, drag

I'm trying to set padding style to my drag node. I can set background-color but not padding.

```
 Y.DD.DDM.on('drag:start', function(e) {

   var drag = e.target;

   drag.get('dragNode').setStyles({
       backgroundColor: drag.get('node').getStyle('backgroundColor'),                   
       padding: drag.get('node').getStyle('padding')
   });
 });
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said here : http://yuilibrary.com/trac-archive/tickets/2528774.html

I have to request all attributes individually with `getComputedStyle()`

```
 paddingTop: drag.get('node').getComputedStyle('paddingTop'),
 paddingBottom: drag.get('node').getComputedStyle('paddingBottom'),
 paddingRight: drag.get('node').getComputedStyle('paddingRight'),
 paddingLeft: drag.get('node').getComputedStyle('paddingLeft')
```

Comment: Moderator: please disregard/delete flag.